# Sort pandas dataframe on index that is string+digits

Tags: python, pandas, string, sorting, digits

I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
col1=['A_100','A_30','A_60','B_100','B_30','B_60']
vals=np.random.randint(0,20,size=6).tolist()
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1,vals)),columns=['index','vals']).set_index('index')

>>>

       vals
index   
A_100   5
A_30    0
A_60    5
B_100   9
B_30    1
B_60    9
```

I want to sort the dataframe so it will be  organized based on the letters of the string and then on th nnumerical value, like this:

```
          val
index
A_100     5
A_60      0
A_30      5
B_100     9
B_60      1
B_30      9
```

I have tried use sort index:

```
df.sort_index()
```

but that returned the same dataframe.
I have also tried to do it by reset index and sort values but I get the same result:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df.sort_values('index')
>>>#nothin changed

df['indexNumber'] = df.index.str.rsplit('_').str[-1].astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(['indexNumber']).drop('indexNumber', axis=1)
>>>#new dataframe but now I have it A,B,A,B and I still need the A to be together and then the B
      vals
index   
A_30    5
B_30    0
A_60    5
B_60    9
A_100   1
B_100   9
```

I assume that the reason is that when it sort the values, it looks on the first digit and then 6 is greater than 3 that greater than 1, and for that reason it believes is already "sorted" , and it doesn't read 100 the number 100.

**Is there any simple way to make it sort by the string (a-b-c order) and then by the number value order? (100,60,30).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onne idea is convert `index` to `Series` with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to `DataFrame`, convert second column to integers and sorting both columns and this index is used for change order in original `df.index` by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = df.index.to_series().str.split('_',expand=True)
df1[1] = df1[1].astype(int)
df1 = df1.sort_values([0, 1], ascending=[True, False])
print (df1)
       0    1
index        
A_100  A  100
A_60   A   60
A_30   A   30
B_100  B  100
B_60   B   60
B_30   B   30

df = df.reindex(df1.index)
print (df)
       vals
index      
A_100     0
A_60     12
A_30     13
B_100    12
B_60      6
B_30      6
```